# python backwards lists

Tags: python, list

say I have a list of numbers [122,423,134] and I wanted to reverse the individual elements so they are [221,324,431], How would I do this in python? reversed(list) and list.reverse() only reverse the order of the elements. Probably something trivial I am sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
In [1]: l = [122,423,134]

In [2]: [int(str(val)[::-1]) for val in l]
Out[2]: [221, 324, 431]
```

Here, `str(val)` converts the element to a string, `[::-1]` reverses the string, and `int()` converts the result to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> _list=[122,423,134]
>>> _list=[int("".join(reversed(str(i)))) for i in _list]
>>> _list
[221, 324, 431]
```

another solution:

```
>>> def reverse_number(i):
...     i=str(i)
...     i=i[::-1]
...     i=int(i)
...     return i
... 
>>> _list=[122,423,134]
>>> map(reverse_number,_list)
[221, 324, 431]
or
>>>> [reverse_number(i) for i in _list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either map or a list compahension to transform each element of a list. Given a function named xform you can do:

```
newlist = map(xform, oldlist)
```

Or:

```
newlist = [xform(a) for a in oldlist]
```

Now you just need to write the xform function.

```
def decimalreverse(i):
    l = reversed(str(i))
    return int(''.join(l))
```